# How to identify Adobe flash player pop-up window using selenium for validation?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way selenium can identify and validate a Adobe flash player pop-up window?

say, you visit this site (http://sports.coral.co.uk/#) and click on "Coral Radio" submenu under Sports Menu. It opens a Adobe pop-up window. I can validate the presence of a pop-up window opening and close it, but I want to know if there is a way to assert on some content of that window? at least the title of the page before I close it?

Thanks for responding if anyone knows how to deal with this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

To switch to a popup window, you need to use `driver.getWindowHandles()` and iterate through them. Then you can use `driver.getTitle();`

I've never found a way to get any content from Flash. I've heard something about automatic screenshots in headless mode, but then you have to check it manually probably again.